# Help compute the fundamental group of a space

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $X = \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \vert xy = 0\}$, and $Y$ is $X$ minus the origin. I want to compute the fundamental group of $Y$ and decide if $X$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$. And I'm stuck on computing the fundamental group of $Y$.

Comment: I was going to tell the deleted answer, that you can still apply VanKampen. Just more carefully. When you see $Y$ are the union of open neighborhood of each punctured plane, the intersection of those neighborhoods is path connected. You can see that it contracts to two circles glued at their north and south pole. the fundamental group of which you can compute by another application of VanKampen, if you want.

Comment: I still don't see how to find the open neighborhoods.

Comment: Maybe it is easier to see this way. Contract the space to two circles joined at two of their points, like the equator and one of the meridians. Then take one half circle from pole to pole and contract it to a point. You get a wedge of three circles (three circles attached at one point). Do you know how to apply VanKampen to the wedge of three circles?